# Loop through hdfs directories

Tags: hadoop

My HDFS directory structure looks like below.

/user/hive/warehouse/check.db/abcd/date=2015-02-02/xyz=hijk/000000_0
/user/hive/warehouse/check.db/abcd/date=2015-02-02/xyz=pqrs/000000_0

I am trying to loop through all the directories under "/user/hive/warehouse/check.db/abcd" and derive 2 fields and am using the below code.

```
INPUT='/user/hive/warehouse/check.db/abcd'

for dir in $(hadoop fs -ls $INPUT/*/ | grep -o -e "$INPUT/.*") ; do

    xyz=$(echo $dir | cut -d '=' -f 3)
    date=$(echo $dir | sed 's/.*date=\(.*\)\/xyz.*/\1/g')

done
```

Is it the best way to do this or is there a better alternate way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use Java code or a python script, although this seems to be good enough as well.