# How to unzip multiple zip files in HDFS

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have multiple zip files in HDFS containing two types of files(`A.csv` & `B.csv`)

**HDFS location**

```
/data/jan.zip --> contains A.csv & B.csv 
/data/feb.zip --> contains A.csv & B.csv
```

I want to extract the files to HDFS location as below

```
/data/jan/A.csv
/data/jan/B.csv
/data/feb/A.csv
/data/feb/B.csv
```

I am looking for some command like below in any tech(spark, pig, hive,..)

```
hadoop fs -unzip hdfs://..../abc.zip
```

Comment: check this http://blog.puneethabm.in/hadoop-hdfs-commands/

Comment: I tried the command given in the blog but it didn't work. It is creating some txt file with the header of the zip file & random chars

Answer (score 1):

I made it by Python 3 from my local pc in remote hdfs. If it helps ... Great than!
You can adapt following script to your pyspark.

You need following libruaries:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from io import BytesIO
from hdfs import Client, HdfsError
```

First two are native an "hdfs" should be installed. 
I used https://pypi.org/project/hdfs/. You can use other whatever you like.

So, here is the script:

```
hdfs_client = Client('s%:s%') % (YOUR_HDFS_HOST, YOUR_HDFS_PORT)
main_dir_path = '/data'

for fls in hdfs_client.list(main_dir_path):
    file_path = '%s/%s' % (main_dir_path, fls)

    if fls.find('.zip') != -1:
        file_name, file_suffix = fls.split('.')
        fold_new_name = '%s/%s' % (main_dir_path, file_name)

        try:
            hdfs_client.makedirs(fold_new_name)
            print(fold_new_name)
        except HdfsError as h_err:
            print(h_err)

        with hdfs_client.read(file_path) as reader:
            zip_content = reader.read()
            zip_file = ZipFile(BytesIO(zip_content))

            for z_fls in zip_file.namelist():
                single_file_content = zip_file.read(z_fls)
                zip_file_new_path = '%s/%s' % (fold_new_name, z_fls)
                hdfs_client.write(zip_file_new_path, single_file_content)
                print('%s file extracted' % zip_file_new_path)
```

I know that's a pretty dump solution but it works.
Hope that it helps for someone.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use UNIX `pipes`.
   In your case you need to loop through data folder in hdfs and for each zip you need to execute below example like command

For example : 
    ***`hadoop fs -cat abc.zip | unzip -d xxxx | hadoop fs -put src dest`***

2. you can use identitymapper this may be bit odd.
3. You can try [**`FileUtils`**](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html) via Java which has below methods.
   I was searching in Hadoop API and I got this I haven't tried this but as per doc it may work.
   [image]

Comment: First option didn't work. Can you please check it once let me know

Comment: @Munesh:Was my answer helpful? If so can you pls. accept it

Comment: While executing the given command hadoop fs .., below error is thrown.

error:  must specify directory to which to extract with -d option
put: `<DIR>/test': No such file or directory
cat: Unable to write to output stream.                                                          Can you please chk once let me know what am I missing b4 accepting the answer?

Comment: That's example command, which gives idea. Moreover, unzip is Linux command which you can see manual page(http://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip)   -d option expects directory to unzip. Also see this example of how to loop through hdfs directories (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685471/loop-through-hdfs-directories) But in your case you need to loop through zip under one directory. Unfortunately I cant able to test now as I don't have cluster or VM to test.

Comment: I'm quite sure that FileUtils will work, if you integrate from Java. If you want to use Java solution, you need to loop through zip files under one HDFS directory and you need to unzip each using FileUtils method. & I don't know python.

Comment: Thank. Yes I know that the Java approach work but I am not looking for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111469/discussion-between-munesh-and-ramprasad-g).