# Loop over files in HDFS directory

Tags: bash, hadoop, hdfs

I need to loop over all csv files in a Hadoop file system. I can list all of the files in a HDFS directory with

```
> hadoop fs -ls /path/to/directory
Found 2 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hadoop hadoop          2 2016-10-12 16:20 /path/to/directory/tmp
-rwxr-xr-x   3 hadoop hadoop 4691945927 2016-10-12 19:37 /path/to/directory/myfile.csv
```

and can loop over all files in a standard directory with

```
for filename in /path/to/another/directory/*.csv; do echo $filename; done
```

but **how can I combine the two?** I've tried

```
for filename in `hadoop fs -ls /path/to/directory | grep csv`; do echo $filename; done
```

but that gives me some nonsense like

```
Found
2
items
drwxr-xr-x

hadoop
hadoop
2    
2016-10-12
....
```

Comment: `hadoop fs -ls /path/to/directory | grep csv` should give you a list of lines of standard out, not necessarily just filenames.

Comment: See in another question a nice way todo a loop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685471/loop-through-hdfs-directories

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work

```
for filename in `hadoop fs -ls /path/to/directory | awk '{print $NF}' | grep .csv$ | tr '\n' ' '`
do echo $filename; done
```

Comment: This works like a charm! But it prints the entire path to the file. How can I cut it short so that it prints only the file name??

Comment: For anyone looking for a similar solution,  use 'cut' to get the substring.          $(echo $filename | cut -f4 -d/)

Comment: I can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash for short

Comment: It would be great if someone could explain how this works

Comment: It works for me when I run it in the shell, but when I run it through a script, the loop runs only once. The output is a single string that contains the full filename of each file in the directory. The trim operation removes the newline character and replaces it with a space and turns every line of the -ls output to a single space separated line. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The `-C` option will display only the file paths.

```
for filename in $(hadoop fs -ls -C /path/to/directory/*.csv); do
    echo "${filename}"
done
```